# Read file text using pandas skiping space in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

my data has the following format. The dataframe doesn't have a header an i can't rebuild the csv. I want to read this file using pandas. I have space in column 4 that i want to keep.
I try to use this:

```
df = pd.read_csv ( 'datasource.csv' , sep= '\s+' , engine= 'python' )
 

    202001YYYY 0101   S5387140320101                FUSELA-CANAL18 aaaa   20200116AIT1206000016           201252552588252525          01 01002  8558569641      0010 0001  00002RATTR00000        170.00 0000000        340.00 109200217378
    202001YYYY 0101   S5517000290210                FUSELA-CONICAL SERE   20200120AIT1206000117           214782523363200113          01 01002  8558569642      0010 0001  00008RATTR00000       2912.82 0000000      23302.56 109200229739
    202001YYYY 0101   S5517000290210                FUSELA-CONICAL AZER   20200120AIT1206000118           296385241152200113          01 01002  8558569643      0010 0001  00003RATTR00000       2912.82 0000000       8738.46 109200233248
    202001YYYY 0101   S5387140320101                FUSELAA               20200117AIT1206000020           201258963255558588          01 01002  8558569644      0010 0001  00003RATTR00000        170.00 0000000        510.00 109200217378
    202001YYYY 0101   S5337500122202                FUSELA TYHNN          20200120AIT1206000119           201478933663636363          01 01002  8558569645      0010 0001  00003RATTR00000        814.41 0000000       2443.23 109200218022
    202001YYYY 0101   S5337500122202                FUSELA RTGYU          20200120AIT1206000120           278965412333333625          01 01002  8558569646      0010 0001  00004RATTR00000        814.41 0000000       3257.64 109200222120
    202001YYYY 0101   S5367140300400                FUSELAEE SERVICE DOOR 20200120AIT1206000129           202010048420200113          01 01002  9200235812      0010 0001  00001EAUSD00000       1700.00 0000000       1700.00 109200235812
    202001YYYY 0101   S5517200000852                FUSELATYHJJ EDGE ASSY-LH20200117AIT1206000076         202010022320200110          01 01002  9200222563      0010 0001  00001EAUSD00000      10474.90 0000000      10474.90 109200222563
```

The output expected:

```
name1      name2  name3           name4                 name5                  name6               name7 name9  name10          name11 name12 name13                name14 name15         name16 name17
202001YYYY 0101   S5387140320101  FUSELA-CANAL18 aaaa   20200116AIT1206000016  201252552588252525  01    01002  8558569641      0010   0001  00002RATTR00000        170.00 0000000        340.00 109200217378
202001YYYY 0101   S5517000290210  FUSELA-CONICAL SERE   20200120AIT1206000117  214782523363200113  01    01002  8558569642      0010   0001  00008RATTR00000       2912.82 0000000      23302.56 109200229739
202001YYYY 0101   S5517000290210  FUSELA-CONICAL AZER   20200120AIT1206000118  296385241152200113  01    01002  8558569643      0010   0001  00003RATTR00000       2912.82 0000000       8738.46 109200233248
202001YYYY 0101   S5387140320101  FUSELAA               20200117AIT1206000020  201258963255558588  01    01002  8558569644      0010   0001  00003RATTR00000        170.00 0000000        510.00 109200217378
202001YYYY 0101   S5337500122202  FUSELA TYHNN          20200120AIT1206000119  201478933663636363  01    01002  8558569645      0010   0001  00003RATTR00000        814.41 0000000       2443.23 109200218022
202001YYYY 0101   S5337500122202  FUSELA RTGYU          20200120AIT1206000120  278965412333333625  01    01002  8558569646      0010   0001  00004RATTR00000        814.41 0000000       3257.64 109200222120
202001YYYY 0101   S5367140300400  FUSELAEE SERVICE DOOR 20200120AIT1206000129  202010048420200113  01    01002  9200235812      0010   0001  00001EAUSD00000       1700.00 0000000       1700.00 109200235812
202001YYYY 0101   S5517200000852  FUSELATYHJJ EDGE ASSY-LH20200117AIT12060000  202010022320200110  01    01002  9200222563      0010   0001  00001EAUSD00000      10474.90 0000000      10474.90 109200222563
```

I try to process each line individually to build the dataframe like this:

```
 import re
import pandas as pd

data = {
  'c1': [],
  'c2': [],
  'c3': [],
  'c4': [],
  'c5': [],
  'c6': [],
  'c7': [],
  'c8': [],
  'c9': [],
  'c10': [],
  'c11': [],
  'c12': [],
  'c13': [],
  'c14': [],
  'c15': [],
  'c16': [],
  'c17':[],
}
with open('datasource.csv', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12,c13,c14,c15,c16,c17= re.split('\s+', line.strip())
        data['c1'].append(c1)
        data['c2'].append(c2)
        data['c3'].append(c3)
        data['c4'].append(' '.join(c4))
        data['c5'].append(c5)
        data['c6'].append(c6)
        data['c7'].append(c7)
        data['c8'].append(c8)
        data['c9'].append(c9)
        data['c10'].append(c10)
        data['c11'].append(c11)
        data['c12'].append(c12)
        data['c13'].append(c13)
        data['c14'].append(c14)
        data['c15'].append(c15)
        data['c16'].append(c16)
        data['c17'].append(c17)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df
```

Comment: You have mix of spaces b/w columns. e.g. 1st 2 column have 1 space. (`202001YYYY 0101`). 
then column name4 and name5 have `2 spaces` at 1st few lines. Then `1 space` at data value `FUSELAEE SERVICE DOOR 20200120AIT1206000129`. And line # 8, have no space at all `FUSELATYHJJ EDGE ASSY-LH20200117AIT12060000`
Data have inconsistency in spaces b/w columns.  Can you post cleaner data set ?

Comment: my data is like that a mixture of one space, 2 space, 3 space ... in FUSELATYHJJ EDGE ASSY-LH20200117AIT12060000 i forgot one space.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to read a `Fixed Width File` as if it were a `Comma Separated File`.

So you'll want to use the [`pd.read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) method, not `pd.read_csv`.